# What are the side effects of missing async/await in a call chain?

Tags: c#, async-await

The following code came up in review (simplified for the sake of this example):

**Code sample 1**

```
public class Chain
{
    public async Task<string> UI()
    {
        return await MidTier();
    }
    
    private Task<string> MidTier()
    {
        return Database();
    }
    
    private async Task<string> Database()
    {            
        string result = null;
                
        await Task.Run(() => result = "Some data");
    
        return result;
    }        
}
```

Clearly async/await has just been missed from the MidTier method but the code compiles (and runs) correctly. I suppose it is reasonable that the compiler has inferred that the calling code and the called code are async/await operations. This assumption can be tested to a degree as intellisense seems to know that the method and called code are awaitable.

However, if async/await are added, different code is produced under the hood:

**Code sample 2**

```
public class Chain
{
    public async Task<string> UI()
    {
        return await MidTier();
    }

    private async Task<string> MidTier()
    {
        return await Database();
    }

    private async Task<string> Database()
    {            
        string result = null;
        
        await Task.Run(() => result = "Some data");

        return result;
    }        
}
```

The IL produced is different. What is going on here?

[image: IL from code sample 1]

[image: IL from code sample 2]

Comment: Is the question "why changing method signature generate different code" or something else? What is wrong or not as you would expect?

Comment: The code seems to infer that the behaviour is the same but the generated code differs - so what is going on here? What is the side effect of omitting async/await in this case?

Comment: Check this out: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). There is no problem with eliding async/await in your case. Btw according to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the asynchronous methods should have the `Async` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

As Theodor commented (why isn't this an answer?), there are some problems with [eliding `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), but this code doesn't have any of them. For a simple "passthrough" method like this, eliding the `async` and `await` keywords is just fine.

A bit more context:

> the code compiles (and runs) correctly. I suppose it is reasonable that the compiler has inferred that the calling code and the called code are async/await operations.

No, this isn't what's happening, as you can see from the differences in the decompiled code. Rather, the `MidTier` is just returning a task that it got from calling another method.

> intellisense seems to know that the method and called code are awaitable.

It's common to refer to methods as "awaitable", but what this actually means is that the method's *return type* is awaitable. So an `async Task` method is awaitable because it returns `Task`, not because it's `async`.

Furthermore, `async` is an implementation detail. Note that methods without bodies (i.e., abstract or interface methods) cannot be `async`, because that is a specific kind of implementation. And the `MidTier` is using a *different* kind of implementation - it's returning a task object directly instead of using `async` to create one.